# lubuntu13.10 - No Wireless

Tags: wireless, lubuntu

This is my first time using Linux and I am having difficulties with my Wireless.
The Network Manager does not show any Wireless Network options, nor does the Wlan LED light up on my Laptop.

I searched the internet for sollutions and I tried a few Terminal commands to fix Wlan somehow, neither did work.

Here is my lspci output if it helps:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] RS480/RS482/RS485 Host Bridge (rev 10)
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] RC4xx/RS4xx PCI Bridge [int gfx]
00:04.0 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] RC4xx/RS4xx PCI Express Port 1
00:05.0 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] RC4xx/RS4xx PCI Express Port 2
00:06.0 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] RC4xx/RS4xx PCI Express Port 3
00:12.0 IDE interface: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] IXP SB4x0 Serial ATA Controller (rev 80)
00:13.0 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] IXP SB4x0 USB Host Controller (rev 80)
00:13.1 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] IXP SB4x0 USB Host Controller (rev 80)
00:13.2 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] IXP SB4x0 USB2 Host Controller (rev 80)
00:14.0 SMBus: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] IXP SB4x0 SMBus Controller (rev 82)
00:14.1 IDE interface: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] IXP SB4x0 IDE Controller (rev 80)
00:14.2 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] IXP SB4x0 High Definition Audio Controller (rev 01)
00:14.3 ISA bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] IXP SB4x0 PCI-ISA Bridge (rev 80)
00:14.4 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] IXP SB4x0 PCI-PCI Bridge (rev 80)
00:18.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] K8 [Athlon64/Opteron] HyperTransport Technology Configuration
00:18.1 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] K8 [Athlon64/Opteron] Address Map
00:18.2 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] K8 [Athlon64/Opteron] DRAM Controller
00:18.3 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] K8 [Athlon64/Opteron] Miscellaneous Control
01:05.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] RS482M [Mobility Radeon Xpress 200]
02:01.0 Ethernet controller: Broadcom Corporation NetXtreme BCM5788 Gigabit Ethernet (rev 03)
02:04.0 CardBus bridge: Texas Instruments PCIxx12 Cardbus Controller
02:04.1 FireWire (IEEE 1394): Texas Instruments PCIxx12 OHCI Compliant IEEE 1394 Host Controller
02:04.2 Mass storage controller: Texas Instruments 5-in-1 Multimedia Card Reader (SD/MMC/MS/MS PRO/xD)
02:04.3 SD Host controller: Texas Instruments PCIxx12 SDA Standard Compliant SD Host Controller
30:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Corporation BCM4311 802.11a/b/g (rev 01)
```

Comment: This link may help: http://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/how-to-install-broadcom-wireless-drivers-bcm43xx

Answer (score 0):

Your Broadcom 4311 requires firmware that is not installed by default in a new install. Please get a temporary wired ethernet connection, open a terminal and do:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-firmware-nonfree
```

Detach the ethernet, reboot and you should be all set.